# What is a good system to evaluate a Fairy-piece value?

Tags: evaluation, pieces

I am creating a Fairy-chess game. Means a chess game with not classic pieces. What is a good strategy to evaluate chess values?

What first comes to my mind is to value the pieces regarding to how many squares they control if you position them in the center. 
Is there a better approach?

Comment: Suddenly I cant apply the regression method, because there are no recorded (or to less for a statistical analysys) games

Comment: Well, first of all, an amazon(N+Q)can be evaluated to have value 9+3=12, and to add another point since it isn't two pieces, Thus giving it point count of 13. Essentially, you can find the sums and add 1. However, there is no easy solution for pieces with absolutely new moves.